# rsync giving "Directory has vanished" when there are multiple (existing) source directories

Tags: rsync

This is happening to me:

```
$ rsync -av ./foo ./bar $DEST
sending incremental file list
directory has vanished: "/path/to/foo"
```

`foo` exists and is regular a regular dir, and `rsync -av ./foo $DEST` works, same for `bar`.

Is "directory has vanished" just how rsync tells me that it doesn't know how to work with multiple sources? Or am I importantly misinterpretting the (*long*) man page?

Comment: What is the value of `$DEST`?

Comment: user@dest.com:dest and /tmp/dest give the same result. (With and without trailing slash.)

Answer (score -1):

This happens at times where the directory is busy, such as another script is accessing the file during the transfer.

As in using [BackupPC](http://backuppc.sourceforge.net/) trying to live migrate in a virtual environment i.e.:

```
directory has vanished: "/var/lib/vz/private/210/var/lib/backuppc/pc/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/1/f%2f/fusr/fshare/fyum-cli"
```

Comment: That may well be one case where this error occurs, but it's a common error with a zillion possible causes.